# suser_sname() returning values in different cases in sql server 2000 and sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I have a user name 'abc'(user name in small letterS) in both sql server 2000 and sql server 2005.

First I logged in through sql server 2000 by entering user name as 'ABC'. After logging in I ran the query 'SELECT SUSER_SNAME()' and got the result as 'ABC'(in caps)

But if I logged in to Sql server 2005 by entering user name as 'ABC' and run the query 'SELECT SUSER_SNAME()', i got the result as 'abc'(in small letters)

Can anyone please tell why im getting like this in sql server 2005. I need the result in capital letter without changing the above query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply chnage to UPPERCASE with UPPER()

Comment: @Mitch: I want the same result without changing code.

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck. Do both servers have the same locale and DB collation?

Comment: Unfortunately both have same locale and collation :(

Comment: My english is betraying me. Could you please check how the LOGIN is spelled out in both servers? To be clear, when you open nodes security|Logins in SSMS do they differ? My Sql Server 2008 shows loginname exactly as written down there.

Comment: Login name is spelled as same in both the servers. I logged into Sql server 2000 machine with the user name as 'ABC'(i entered user name in capital letters, but user name is in small letters when we see in security->Logins node in SSMS). When I run the above mentioned query, here I get the result as 'ABC'(in capital letters). But when I follow the same process in Sql Server 2005, I get the result in small letters.